# How to distinguish the commonly printed keyboard keys from the rest

Tags: java, input, keyboard, lwjgl

I want to collect keyboard input and append it together in a java StringBuilder, but using LWJGL's Keyboard event, i end up fetching more than I wish, like Shift, CapsLock, Escape, F1 to F12, Enter, even punctuation etc.. These keys also have key ID's, but by appending them, they are printed as a square (unrecognized character i believe).

My goal is to ignore these non-printable keys without having to create a giant array with all these unwanted keys. Is there any way to do so?

P.S. Mind that i wish the common symbols like \,.-< etc. to still be considered into the string, like any text editor would.

Comment: you could get the character they represent and cast to an int. Then use the ASCII values available here http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html  to create an inclusive range.

Comment: So you're able to convert the keyboard event codes to `char` and add them with `StringBuilder`?  How do you do this--`getEventCharacter()`?  If that works, then what does `getEventCharacter()` return for `Shift`, `CapsLock`, `F1-F12`?  I don't know anything about LWJGL, I'm just looking at the javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark W I just found out that the ASCII range from 32 to 126 and 128 to 255 covers, i believe, every single character that is commonly printed in the everyday text-editors. Thanks a bunch :)

Here is a minimal code chunk that might be useful for someone using lwjgl

```
private StringBuilder text;

    private void updateInput()
    {
        while (Keyboard.next())
        {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
            {
                // get key info
                int key = Keyboard.getEventKey();
                char ch = Keyboard.getEventCharacter();
                int ascii = (int) ch;

                // delete case
                if(key == Keyboard.KEY_BACK)
                    text.setLength(Math.max(0, text.length() - 1));

                // append if common char
                if((ascii >= 32 && ascii <= 126) || (ascii >= 128 && ascii <= 255))
                    text.append(ch);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful about 128-159.  In the "real" ASCII, those are defined _not_ to be printable characters.  However, on Windows systems, they tend to redefine those character values to be other symbols.  I don't know what platform you're on or whether LWJGL could return values in that range, but you might need to do some experimenting or further research and then decide whether you want the second range to start at `128` or `160`.

Comment: Great tip mate, nice complement to the answer, I will make sure to experiment on such ^^ Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you could use. This example is then used as an inner class and you use it in stead of a regular ActionListener on a component. This example catches the keycode of the event (using KeyEvent). I placed some examples you asked in your questions, I'm sure you'll find more if needed.

You should append a custom string to your existing string in every case of the switch statement.

```
public class CustomListener extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            try {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT:
                            //Append a string to your existing string
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_F1:
                            //Append a string to your existing string
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK:
                            //Append a string to your existing string
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                            //Append a string to your existing string
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```